# Single Custom Wordpress Child Page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, php-include

I have 5+ blogs that I manage and I'm trying to make the page layout a little more efficient for updates. For each blog, they have about 5-6 custom pages with generally the same code, except for the content area. This is an example of what I've written successfully already.

(*sorry for the length, trying to be thorough on the background here*)

```
<?php 

/* Template Name: Contributors Page */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
            <div id="left-area">
                <?php include 'content-contributors.php'; ?>
            </div> <!-- #left-area -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- #content-area -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This code would be standard on all custom pages except for the include link.

For example, I would use the line `<?php include 'content-contributors.php'; ?>` to call the following file:

```
<?php 

// Get all users, display in alphabetical order
$allUsers = get_users('role=contributor&orderby=display_name&order=ASC&exclude=');

$users = array();

// Remove subscribers from the list as they won't write any articles
foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
{
    if(!in_array( 'subscriber', $currentUser->roles ))
    {
        $users[] = $currentUser;
    }
}

?>

<section class="author-content" role="main">
<!-- insert content here -->
</section>
```

Since this would be very repetitive when updating upwards of 20-30 some pages, I wanted to shrink this down to one custom page per blog. Here's what I tried:

```
<?php 

/* Template Name: Custom Page */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
            <div id="left-area">
                <?php include get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/inc-page-content.php'; ?>
            </div> <!-- #left-area -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- #content-area -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here I've replaced the original include with `<?php include get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/inc-page-content.php'; ?>` and calls this file:

```
<?php
    if ( is_page( 'archives' ) ) {
        echo "include get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "'/content-archives.php'";
    }
    elseif ( is_page( 'contributors' ) ) {
        echo "include get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "'/content-contributors.php'";
    }
    elseif ( is_page( 'subscribe' ) ) {
        echo "include get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "'/content-subscribe.php'";
    }
    elseif ( is_page( 'sitemap' ) ) {
        echo "include get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "'/content-sitemap.php'";
    }
    elseif ( is_page( 'tags' ) ) {
        echo "include get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "'/content-tag_cloud.php'";
    }
    elseif ( is_page( 'thankyou' ) ) {
        echo "include get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "'/content-thankyou.php'";
    }

    else {
        // do nothing
    }

?>
```

Unfortunately nothing happens. I've looked over my code and thought it made sense. Hopefully this is a simple fix. Maybe I'm over-complicating things.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Weird.. your solution with is_page() should work. Can you check what's the page slug of the current page? (`global $post;` and `echo $post->post_name;`)

Comment: Btw you dont need to use `echo`, just the `include`. You are calling the `include` function, not printing a string. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Clyff, I confirmed the post and it was matching up.

Comment: Your syntax looks all wrong. See the syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns the stylesheet `URI` (`URL`) - you can't include a php-file through a `URL` (actually you can in some cases, but you **very** rarely *should*).

You should use `get_stylesheet_directory()` instead.

Also, as @Clyff pointed out, don't wrap `include` statements in `echo` statements - what you are doing is turning them into strings (and what's more your syntax in those lines is way off, your quotes don't add up, so I'm surprised if you don't get any fatal errors...?)

To include a file from the theme root do this:

```
include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/content-thankyou.php';
```

...or if you are already in another file in the theme root, this should do:

```
include 'content-thankyou.php';
```

BTW I don't really see any reason to include a file whose only purpose is to include other files. If I understand what you are trying to do, you can just put the whole thing in your custom template:

```
<?php 

/* Template Name: Contributors Page */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
            <div id="left-area">
                <?php
                if ( is_page( 'archives' ) ) {
                    include 'content-archives.php';
                } elseif ( is_page( 'contributors' ) ) {
                    include 'content-contributors.php';
                } elseif ( is_page( 'subscribe' ) ) {
                    include 'content-subscribe.php';
                } elseif ( is_page( 'sitemap' ) ) {
                    include 'content-sitemap.php';
                } elseif ( is_page( 'tags' ) ) {
                    include 'content-tag_cloud.php';
                } elseif ( is_page( 'thankyou' ) ) {
                    include 'content-thankyou.php';
                } else {
                    // do nothing
                }
                ?>
            </div> <!-- #left-area -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- #content-area -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for catching that @Mikk3IRo and @Clyff!